# Can you effectively typedef a forward-declared class from a C++ header in the implementation file?

Tags: c++, header, typedef

In C++ I want to have an implementation-specific class declared in my header like so:

```
// .h header file
class MyHiddenClass;
void doSomething(MyHiddenClass* data);
```

Then in my implementation file I would love to be able to use a typedef or something similar to say that, in my implementation file, MyHiddenClass is actually something like an NSView that is fully defined elsewhere:

```
// .cpp implementation file    
typedef NSView MyHiddenClass;
void doSomething(MyHiddenClass* data) {
    // call NSView functions on data
}
```

However, I get an error that I'm redefining MyHiddenClass, even though it was only forward-declared. I know I can fully define MyHiddenClass in the implementation file as a wrapper and give it a data member of type NSView, but it seems like there ought to be a way to just tell the compiler to know that MyHiddenClass pointers in the implementation file are actually just NSView pointers, without revealing that info in the header file. Any ideas?

Comment: Dunno what to tell you, expect that C++ does not work this way. Once `class myHiddenClass` is declared, you're done. The goose is cooked. The cat is out of the bag. It's `myHiddenClass`, or bust. There are no other options but to define `myHiddenClass`, and go with the flow. There are no other options. It's `myHiddenClass`. It can't be `someOtherClass`, and a `typedef` is not going to change that. That's pretty much all there's to say about this. You're fully committed to this function's parameter being `myHiddenClass`, and nothing else. The End.

Comment: A type must be defined before you can make an alias to it.

Comment: One convention is to used a `details` namespace where you put your "hidden" code (basically you do not guarantee anything about that code) and then in your actual namespace you have an alias like `using NSView = details::super_cool_view;`

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to do something like this, but it works as long as your functions only work with pointers. You just have to cast the `Hidden` pointer in the `.cpp` always into your target type, or vice versa.

`hidden.hpp`

```
#pragma once

class Hidden;

Hidden* create();
void set(Hidden* ptr, int value);
void print(Hidden* ptr);
void destroy(Hidden* ptr);
```

`hidden.cpp`

```
#include "hidden.hpp"
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int value;
};

Hidden* to_hidden(Node* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Hidden*>(ptr);
}

Node* from_hidden(Hidden* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Node*>(ptr);
}

Hidden* create() {
    return to_hidden(new Node{0});
}

void set(Hidden* ptr, int value) {
    auto node = from_hidden(ptr);
    node->value = value;

}

void print(Hidden* ptr) {
    std::cout << "Hidden value is " << from_hidden(ptr)->value << '\n';
}

void destroy(Hidden* ptr) {
    delete from_hidden(ptr);
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "hidden.hpp"

int main() {
    auto ptr = create();
    print(ptr);
    set(ptr, 5);
    print(ptr);
    destroy(ptr);
}
```

```
Hidden value is 0
Hidden value is 5
```

`reinterpret_cast`'s are error prone, so I wrap them in the `to_hidden` and `from_hidden` functions. These functions are declared `static` because they are not part of the public interface. This way they do not conflict with any functions of the same name in other `.cpp` files.

Make sure that you only declare the class `Hidden` and do not define it! This way the compiler will report an error if you accidentally try to dereference `Hidden` somewhere before casting the pointer to `Node`.

## Usage with smart pointers

This approach also works with smart pointers. The `create` function returns a `unique_ptr`. Note that for `unique_ptr` the signature of the deleter is part of the datatype. We want to use `destroy` again for deleting, we have to pass this to `unique_ptr` as a pointer. `destroy` is a function with a pointer to `hidden` as parameter and `void` as return type.

`hidden.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class Hidden;
using hidden_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Hidden, void(*)(Hidden*)>;

hidden_unique_ptr create();
void set(Hidden* ptr, int value);
void print(Hidden* ptr);
```

The `destroy` function itself does not need to be in the header now. We make it `static` within the `.cpp` accordingly.

`hidden.cpp`

```
#include "hidden.hpp"
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int value;
};

static Hidden* to_hidden(Node* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Hidden*>(ptr);
}

static Node* from_hidden(Hidden* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Node*>(ptr);
}

static void destroy(Hidden* ptr) {
    delete from_hidden(ptr);
}

hidden_unique_ptr create() {
    return hidden_unique_ptr(to_hidden(new Node{0}), &destroy);
}

void set(Hidden* ptr, int value) {
    auto node = from_hidden(ptr);
    node->value = value;

}

void print(Hidden* ptr) {
    std::cout << "Hidden value is " << from_hidden(ptr)->value << '\n';
}
```

To call the functions we must now always use the `get()` function to turn the smart pointer into a raw pointer. In turn, we no longer have to worry about deleting anything; the Smart Pointer now reliably takes care of that itself.

Note that you can convert a `unqiue_ptr` into a `shared_ptr` at any time! With `shared_ptr` it is also not necessary to encode the deleter in the datatype. The usage is therefore a bit easier than with `unique_ptr`.

`main.cpp`

```
#include "hidden.hpp"

void worker(std::shared_ptr<Hidden> shared){
    set(shared.get(), 7);
    print(shared.get());
}

int main() {
    auto ptr = create(); // unique_ptr
    print(ptr.get());

    std::shared_ptr<Hidden> shared = std::move(ptr);
    worker(shared);
    print(shared.get());
    set(shared.get(), 5);
    print(shared.get());
}
```

```
Hidden value is 0
Hidden value is 7
Hidden value is 7
Hidden value is 5
```